# python find unique and put it alphabetical order

Tags: python, file, unique, alphabetical

I need to find into a text file and print out both the UNIQUE words AND put in alphabetical order
i know how read a file and get alphabetical but Im running into an issue with the sort and unique(I honestly don't how to do this one)

Also another problem i have is that while it gives me the words in alphabetical order is gives me "\n" each time it finds a word

TEXTFILE: 
mike,
sara
sara
adam
william

```
A= open('Wordfile.txt')
line=sorted(A.readlines())

while len(line)!=0:
print(line, end =' ')
line=A.readline()


A.close();
```

output: Adam, mike \n, sara \n, sara\n, william\n

Comment: Can you add an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do:

```
A = open('Wordfile.txt')
lines = sorted(list(set([line.rstrip() for line in A])))    # Used rstip() to remove '\n' and set() to make items unique.

for line in lines:
    print(line, end =' ')

A.close()
```

Comment: ahh yes thank I'm gonna have to remember that "set" is a thing